# Auto Layout view resizing frustrations when designing in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

**Problem: UIView size is "locked" when designing with Auto Layout in IB**

I've uploaded a 20 second video that illustrates my problem, but let me describe it. You may recognize the project: it's right out of Apple's WWDC 2012 "Introduction to Auto Layout." I've got a simple iPhone view in Interface Builder where I've already got a button and label along the bottom. The next step is to add a UIView. Here's where things get ugly.

When I drag the UIView out of the palette in Interface Builder and onto the iPhone window, as soon as I let it go it seems to become *locked* in to its starting size. I place it in the upper left corner, and I'd like to drag it horizontally to the right side of the window, and vertically to where it will be up against (minus the padding) the button and label along the bottom. But, when I try to resize it, I cannot. It's stuck on its original size!

The video illustrating my problem is here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsW4UwnCEkw

You can see me grab the right edge of the view and try to pull it along to the right side of the window, but it won't expand. You can then see me move the entire view to the right side (it retains its size) and then try the opposite: grabbing the left side and trying to expand it so that it sizes up against the left side of the window. In both cases, the view is simply locked to its original size.

What gives! Auto Layout in Interface Builder is just the most frustrating thing. How do I resize a view by dragging? Thanks!

(Note: Xcode 4.6.3.)

Comment: This sort of thing is fixed in Xcode 5. When I used to do it in Xcode 4 I just resized the view from the info panel by increasing / decreasing the numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that the functionality was at one time working in an earlier version of Xcode 4 (the one used at the time of the WWDC 2012), and then the functionality broke in a later version? I just don't understand why the presenter is able to do it in her Xcode and I'm unable to. (I've already begun playing with Xcode 5, but I've also just begun migrating to Auto Layout, and I'm trying to figure it out. I'm not loading iOS 7 onto my devices while it's in beta, so I'm stuck with Xcode 4 for some coding.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In IB, in the series of buttons in the lower right hand corner, click on the rightmost button:

[image: rightmost button]

When you do, you'll see a "When resizing Views Apply Constraints To..." pop-up menu:

[image: When resizing Views Apply Constraints To...]

Make sure that "Siblings and Ancestors" is *not* checked.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I tried searching for an answer, but couldn't find one. (Maybe there is one already that I missed.) So, I tried to put as many keywords in my title (etc.) as I could, in part to help anyone else who came across this. Thanks!!!

Comment: Sadly that's not there these days! 2021

Comment: Or another way of looking at it: Fortunately this feature is rendered unnecessary in modern Xcode versions!

Comment: @Rob Well I still cannot resize my view inside a stack in xcode 14... so not unnecessary, even when i resize it manually, it is reset to it's previous size. The only way was to get them out of the stack, resize them and then stack them again.